# Are these three commands \bigl( , \big( and \bigr( interchangeable?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I am looking for the **visual** differences between `\big(`, `\bigl(`, and `\bigr(` in math mode?

Comment: the spacing is different, just try an example.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelFraiman. How can  I delete my question?

Comment: As you have not received any answers you should be able to delete your own question, there should be a delete button at the bottom, but you haven't  received any downvotes and there's nothing wrong with a duplicate, it makes it easier for other people having the same problem to find the answer. your dupe can act as a kind of signpost, no need to panic delete